# Pandas: Not seperating rows into colums

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

## First Pandas Project

Starting to learn pandas and wanted to test with a dataset of my weightlifting which I exported as a CSV format. The purpose of this was to analyze my progression, but I have unfortunately run into an issue where my data rows are all stored in the same column and not splitting the data into the different columns which looks correct based on the imported header.

I've tried to add the seperator function while importing the csv, but looking at the data it needs to be "," that seperates the values (I guesss CSV always takes comma as default).

### I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("strong.csv")
```

### Data from CSV looks like this:

```
Date,Workout Name,Exercise Name,Set Order,Weight,Reps,Distance,Seconds,Notes,Workout Notes


2018-05-08 19:27:54,"1: Back, Biceps & Abs","Deadlift (Barbell)",1,50,12,0,0,"",""


2018-05-08 19:27:54,"1: Back, Biceps & Abs","Deadlift (Barbell)",2,50,10,0,0,"",""

2018-05-08 19:27:54,"1: Back, Biceps & Abs","Deadlift (Barbell)",3,110,1,0,0,"",""
```

### See image to see data.head() result:

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWiUj.png )

#### EDIT: See link to CSV file with first columns.

https://github.com/Trools/StrongProject

Comment: Are you sure you copied the correct data in your question? Works for me with the given example data without any problems.

Comment: and if you try to add sep=',' in the parameters of read_csv() ? or with sep=';'

Comment: sep=',' doesnt change anything.

Yes, I just copied them directly from the CSV and my Jupyter notebook.
Could it perhaps be related to issues with lines further down. I only shared 3 lines, but have a total of 3000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an error in the CSV export.

I just tried creating a new file with the same data and suddently I dot an error about 11 lines instead of 10 existing in row 134. When going through the file, I found that one of the last data entries (weight) was stored as 72,5 instead of 72.5 which resulted in the issues of having an additional seperated value.

I am however a little confused why Pandas didnt give this error when trying to load the data in Jupyter notebook?

How would one go about an issue where a CSV export is not correctly formated?